# Convert list of dictionaries with different keys to values string list

Tags: python, html, list, dictionary

Example list of dicts:

```
[{'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}]
```

Expected out = `['aly', '104', 'Not A name', '99']`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the great answers. If I would like the output to be like this :  ['aly' : '104', 'Not A name': '99'] what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in one line:

```
d = [{'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}]

[v for i in d for k,v in i.items()]
```

The result will be:

```
Out[1]: ['aly', '104', 'Not A name', '99']
```

Comment: Can I add a question please? What should I change in order of the expected result to be ['aly' : '104', 'Not A name': '99'] ?

Comment: @Alo
```listDictionary = [{'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}]

out = []
for i in listDictionary:
    out.append(i['name'] + ':' + i['age'])
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

```
listDictionary = [{'name': 'aly', 'age': '104'}, {'name': 'Not A name', 'age': '99'}]
out = []
for i in listDictionary:
    for k, v in i.items():
        out.append(v)
print(out)
```

Output : `['aly', '104', 'Not A name', '99']`